# What is the steps to be taken when you suspect a linux malware has infected your computer?

Tags: malware, linux, backdoor, trojan

Using Linux is a different beast entirely but sometimes malware can blend as seemingly  harmless system binaries like this post
[Bpfdoor](https://elastic.github.io/security-research/intelligence/2022/05/04.bpfdoor/article/)

Like this post which documents a highly evasive Linux malware.

In this case running wireshark will mostly likely not be genuine as the traffic will mostly likely be tampered as it uses a filter **BPF** there are options of deep packet inspection.

AV that use signature might not have a current signature for the malware

As an average Linux user I have moderate knowledge with defense methods to find a suspicious Linux program and quarantine it .

I want to know what are the options steps to successfully detect quarantine and respond to this kind of threat?

Comment: As an average linux user, you are unlikely to be targeted by sophisticated state-sponsored malware. You are also unlikely to have the skill set required to detect (much less effectively respond to) such malware, specially if AVs developed by highly skilled professionals are missing it.

Comment: What outcome are you wanting? What do you *want* to do?